# 2 threads running in parallel and waiting for the same condition

Tags: c, pthreads, condition-variable

2 arrays of the same size are given. 2 threads need to be created, each responsible for 1 array, the threads should work at the same time. After both threads set one element (array_B[i] = ++count;), the arrays should be printed to the screen, wait for a key press, then the threads should continue, and so on.

I am not 100% sure if this should be solved with mutexes or not.
It is working to a certain extent, but the program doesn't stop after 1 update for each array as it is intended.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex_A = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_B = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int array_A[NMax], array_B[NMax];

void *fun_A(void *arg)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NMax ; ++i)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_A);
            array_A[i] = ++count;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_A);
        }
    return NULL;
}

void *fun_B(void *arg)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NMax ; ++i)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_B);
            array_B[i] = ++count;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_B);
        }
    return NULL;
}

void Print()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NMax ; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array_A[i]);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < NMax ; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array_B[i]);

    getch();
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t A_th, B_th;

    pthread_create(&A_th, NULL, &fun_A, NULL);
    pthread_create(&B_th, NULL, &fun_B, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_A);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_B);

        Print();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_A);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_B);
    }

    pthread_join(A_th, NULL);
    pthread_join(B_th, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

Comment: Mutexes guarantee **mut**ual **ex**clusion when used correctly. They do not ensure an order on the operations in general.